# Generating random multiples of 100

Tags: javascript, random

Hi am trying to generate random multiples of 100 using javascript.

I would expect the following to generate a random number between 1000 and 4000. Then check to see if it is a multiple of 100 and if so return it. And if not try generating another number.

I expected that in the else section of the if loop, rand() would just call the function again.

```
 function rand() {
    num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4000) + 1000;
    if (num % 100 == 0) {
      return num;
    } else {
      rand();
    }
  }
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/7tSGNiGQBUAYJsdMVeEr?p=preview

For the distances I am getting undefined instead of multiples of 100

Comment: `rand()` -> `return rand()`. But instead of making it recursive you should just use integer division, e.g. `Math.floor(... / 100) * 100`

Comment: There's gotta be a more deterministic way to generate a multiple of 100 rather than repeated random trials…

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yes that is much nicer, thanks

Comment: so generate a randon number between 10 and 40 and multiple it by 100.....

Comment: "between 1000 and 4000" - how is "(x in [0, 4000[) + 1000" in [1000, 4000]?

Answer (score 11):

> I would expect the following to generate a random number between 1000 and 4000. Then check to see if it is a multiple of 100 and if so return it. And if not try generating another number.

To do that, you'd have to **return** the result of the recursive call to `rand`:

```
} else {
  return rand();
}
```

**But** there's no need whatsoever to do that. To get random multiples of 100 in the range 1000 <= n < 4000:

```
return (Math.floor(Math.random() * 30 + 10)) * 100;
```

E.g., create a random number in the range 10 <= n < 40 and then multiply it by 100. :-)

Live Example:

```js
function rand() {
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * 30 + 10)) * 100;
}

for (var n = 0; n < 100; ++n) {
  console.log(rand());
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: **All**: It should be `Math.floor`, not `Math.round`. Not sure what I was thinking. Fixed above. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your method (generate any random number between 1000 and 4000 and only return multiples of 100) is 100 times slower than necessary and doing it recursively will probably crash the stack. Do a little elementary arithmetic:

```
function rand() { return 100 * Math.floor(30 * Math.random() + 10); }
```

You don't specify whether the 4000 is inclusive or not. If so, make that 30 above a 31.

Answer (score 1):

You are simply missing a return statement, without it, the function is just run and when a match is found it's returned to nothing

```js
function rand() {
  num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4000) + 1000;
  if (num % 100 == 0) {
    return num;
  } else {
    return rand(); //<-- here
  }
}

console.log(rand())
```

Comment: Too late, and T.J. included a better way, too.

Answer (score 1):

Few things here 1, change your rand function to have a different range

```
num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3000) + 1000);
```

Second, you are making a recursive function by calling it inside it self, for this you need to return the value to the past call function, if not the value stays on the last succesfull call.

```
else {
      num = rand();
      return num;
    }
```

Hope this helps :>

```js
function rand() {
    let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3000) + 1000);
    if (num % 100) {
      num = rand();
    }
    return num;
  }
  
console.log(rand());
```

Comment: Too late, and T.J. included a better way, too.

Comment: You should declare `let num` otherwise you're creating an implicit global. You can also just change the `if` / `else` to `if (num % 100) { num = rand(); } return num;`

Comment: OK, it's nice that you've shown him how to correctly do the stupid thing he's doing, but wouldn't it be better to show him how to do the right thing instead?